# Не вставляются куки с прокси

Tags: python, python-3.x, cookie, beautiful-soup, proxy

Я пытаюсь получить HTML часть сайта через:

```
BeautifulSoup(session.get(url, headers = headers, proxies = proxy).content, 'html.parser')
```

Также, заранее добавляю куки:

```
cookies = json.load(open('cookies.json', 'r'))
for cookie in cookies:
    print(cookie)
    session.cookies.set(cookie['name'], cookie['value'])
```

Но мне возвращает:

```
<html><head><script src="/process-qv9ypsgmv9.js"></script></head><body><script>window.onload=function(){process();}</script><noscript><p>Please enable JavaScript and Cookies in your browser.</p></noscript></body></html>
```

Хотя, если из запроса убрать прокси, то есть:

```
BeautifulSoup(session.get(url, headers = headers).content, 'html.parser')
```

Тогда возвращается нормальный HTML код. В чем может быть проблема и как её решить?

Comment: Please enable JavaScript and Cookies in your browser. Куки скорее всего вяжутся к прокси и UA. при смене куки инвалидируются.

Comment: то есть если я получу куки под впном со страной, к которой привязан прокси, тогда все должно работать?

Comment: я могу лишь гадать. хотя как правило так. например Cloudflare выдает куки после проверки именно с такой логикой. ВПН только тут не при чем.